# Berlin public broadcasting payment

Tags: germany, payment

I recently moved to Berlin and I am currently renting a short term apartment. I have completed Anmeldung and I received the broadcasting fee payment registration. My landlord already pays pays it and provided me with the Beitragsnummer.
What do I do next? On the ARD site, I clicked on "Anfrage zur Beitragspflicht beantworten", filled in "Aktenzeichen" and "Postleitzahl".
The only suitable option I see is "Die Wohnung ist bereits auf eine andere, mit mir in der Wohnung lebende Person, angemeldet." But the landlord isn't living in the same apartment. Can I chose that and continue or do I need to deregister the apartment as if I were living with someone else who's paying it?

Comment: Depends on the exact legal status of your rental. The housing market has some developments which do not fit neatly into the legal categories when landlords try to undercut the protections of a normal tenant-landlord relationship.

Comment: Are you Indonesian and lived in Abu Dhabi before? :P

Comment: Is this a sublease? Are you a subtenant? The ransom is generally paid on a per-apartment-basis. One apartment door ≈ one ransom.